# Not able to attach database in SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have SQL Server 2008R2 on my laptop, with a number of databases on it.

I detached one of my development databases today (I wanted to take a copy) using SSMS, and now I can't re-attach it. Whenever I try I get the following error

> CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105) while attempting to open or create the physical file

I have seen numerous similar questions on this, and they always seem to suggest the database being attached to another SQL Server instance. I have checked as to whether I have another SQL Server instance running, can't see anything even remotely like in Task manager. I even restarted the computer to clear any if they were there - no joy.

I read somewhere that if I change the Log On checkbox on the SQL Server Services properties Log On tab to Local System Account that should do it; it didn't.

I am at a complete loss as to where to go next.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Error 5 is Access Denied. It is a permissions issue. You do not have permissions to write to that location. You probably should be an Administrator on that machine.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am an administrator on that machine. I managed to detach the database and that must need the same permissions. When I looked at the properties of that directory, it showed I had Full Control, although Special Permissions was not checked at all.